# VS 2010 watch window configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, watch

When using the debug watch window in VS 2008 (C++), I was pleased to be able to scroll down the entire contents of a very large memory container (sets, maps).  After converting to VS 2010, I can only scroll down 2000 elements.

Is there some way that I can configure VS 2010 for the unlimited scrolling I enjoyed with VS2008?

Comment: Interesting. Does VS crash/slow down, or it just doesn't let you scroll further? Just to be sure, did you install Service Pack1 for VS2010? (Help->About, it should say SP1 in your version info)

Comment: that vs2010 is like a downgrade of vs2008 :(